# Creating a Function for a parabola in R, but not translating upwards

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, graph

I am trying to make a parabola in R to layer on top of my ggplot with the function

y = -(10x-8)^2 + 113

using the code

```
eqn = function(x) {-(10*x - 8)^2 + 113}
```

But when I add it to the ggplot using

```
+ stat_function(fun = eqn) + xlim(115, 0)
```

It's max is 0, when it should be 113, and if I just remove the 113 nothing changes, so I just do not understand why it does not recognize the "+113" at the end there.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the graph correctly? What if you zoom in with `xlim(5, 0)` or `xlim(1, 0)` instead. Is it more clear that the max is 113? I think your y range is just so large it's not easy to tell the max is above 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the values of a `ggplot` using `layer_data`:

```
eqn = function(x) {-(10*x - 8)^2 + 113 }

library(ggplot2)

layer_data(ggplot() + stat_function(fun = eqn) + xlim(115, 0))

...
99    -2.30     -112.00     1    -1  black  0.5        1    NA
100   -1.15      100.75     1    -1  black  0.5        1    NA
101    0.00       49.00     1    -1  black  0.5        1    NA
```

the last value is 49 which is exactly `113 - 8^2` :

```
eqn(0)
[1] 49
```

Perhaps you forgot to source again `eqn` function after adding 113.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
curve(-(10*x-8)^2 + 113, from=-50, to=50,  xlab="x", ylab="y")
```

Using `ggplot2` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
eq = function(x){-(10*x-8)^2 + 113}
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-50, 50)), aes(x=x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=eq)
```

Answer (score 1):

````r
library(ggplot2)


eqn = function(x) {-(10*x - 8)^2 + 113}



``` r
#run as stat_function  
ggplot()+
  stat_function(fun = eqn) + xlim(-1, 2)
````

[image]

```r
# perhaps you meant ylim

ggplot()+
  stat_function(fun = eqn) + ylim(0, 115)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>